# Is there a way to use "column filter" closure in Laravel Eloquent in both "with" and "paginate"?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm using Laravel with Laravel Breeze + React.

I want to do something like this in the GameController:

```
$expiredMatchesPagination = Game::with('homeTeam: id, home_team_id, logo', 'awayTeam: id, away_team_id, logo')             
->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())             
->orderBy('start', 'asc')             
->paginate(
     perPage: 15,
     columns: ['start', 'home_team', 'away_team'],
     pageName: 'expiredMatchesPage');
```

I want to filter some columns from both away and home teams (need logo and name from it only) + I need the game's start date.

I tried many combinations, but I can make either paginate or with column closure work.

Like in my previous example the 'start' filter works but both the home_team and away_team will be null if I log it in React.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i suggest you do something like this if its helps you

```
   $expiredMatchesPagination = Game::with(['homeTeam'=>function($q){
            $q->select('logo', 'name');
        }, 'awayTeam'=>function($q){
            $q->select('logo', 'name');
        }])
            ->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('start', 'asc')
            ->select('start')->paginate([
                    'perPage' => 15,
                    'columns' => ['start', 'home_team', 'away_team'],
                    'pageName'=> 'expiredMatchesPage']
            );
```

This should work because i am selecting the columns i want with the help of the callback function making me been able to pick the columns i want